# Entity Framework testing length in lambda expression

Tags: c#, entity-framework, lambda

I'm trying to write an Entity Framework lambda expression to find records in which a string field has a length greater than zero.  The following code compiles, but does not return the results I was expecting:

```
foreach (CUSTOMER c in (_db.CUSTOMERs.Where<CUSTOMER>(i => i.CUSTPREVIOUSEMAIL.Length > 0)))
{...}
```

The resulting set of customers are coming back including customers whose CUSTPREVIOUSEMAIL value is an empty string.

Why doesn't this work?  How can I make it work?

Here is the generated SQL:

```
SELECT 
"B"."CUSTID" AS "CUSTID", 
"B"."CUSTFNAME" AS "CUSTFNAME", 
"B"."CUSTLNAME" AS "CUSTLNAME", 
"B"."CUSTADDRESS" AS "CUSTADDRESS", 
"B"."CUSTCITY" AS "CUSTCITY", 
"B"."CUSTSTATE" AS "CUSTSTATE", 
"B"."CUSTZIP" AS "CUSTZIP", 
"B"."CUSTTYPE" AS "CUSTTYPE", 
"B"."CUSTPHONE1" AS "CUSTPHONE1", 
"B"."CUSTPHONE2" AS "CUSTPHONE2", 
"B"."CUSTINTCLASS" AS "CUSTINTCLASS", 
"B"."CUSTSPARE1" AS "CUSTSPARE1", 
"B"."CUSTSPARE2" AS "CUSTSPARE2", 
"B"."CUSTDATE1" AS "CUSTDATE1", 
"B"."CUSTDATE2" AS "CUSTDATE2", 
"B"."CUSTEMAIL" AS "CUSTEMAIL", 
"B"."STOREID" AS "STOREID", 
"B"."CUSTDISCOUNT" AS "CUSTDISCOUNT", 
"B"."CUSTTAXEXEMPT" AS "CUSTTAXEXEMPT", 
"B"."CUSTNOTES" AS "CUSTNOTES", 
"B"."CUSTINACTIVE" AS "CUSTINACTIVE", 
"B"."CUSTBDAY" AS "CUSTBDAY", 
"B"."CUSTBADCHECK" AS "CUSTBADCHECK", 
"B"."CUSTDISOUNTCEXPIRES" AS "CUSTDISOUNTCEXPIRES", 
"B"."CUSTTERMS" AS "CUSTTERMS", 
"B"."CUSTPRICELEVEL" AS "CUSTPRICELEVEL", 
"B"."CUSTCREDITLIMIT" AS "CUSTCREDITLIMIT", 
"B"."CUSTTOTALMONEY" AS "CUSTTOTALMONEY", 
"B"."CUSTTOTALVOLUME" AS "CUSTTOTALVOLUME", 
"B"."CUSTTAXEXEMPT2" AS "CUSTTAXEXEMPT2", 
"B"."CUSTTAXEXEMPT3" AS "CUSTTAXEXEMPT3", 
"B"."CUSTPOPUPNOTES" AS "CUSTPOPUPNOTES", 
"B"."CUSTCOMPANY" AS "CUSTCOMPANY", 
"B"."CUSTCOUNTRY" AS "CUSTCOUNTRY", 
"B"."CUSTKEY" AS "CUSTKEY", 
"B"."CUSTTIMESTAMP" AS "CUSTTIMESTAMP", 
"B"."CUSTREFCODE" AS "CUSTREFCODE", 
"B"."CUSTSPARECHECK2" AS "CUSTSPARECHECK2", 
"B"."CUSTSPARECHECK3" AS "CUSTSPARECHECK3", 
"B"."CUSTSPARECHECK4" AS "CUSTSPARECHECK4", 
"B"."CUSTSPARECHECK5" AS "CUSTSPARECHECK5", 
"B"."CUSTTAXCODE" AS "CUSTTAXCODE", 
"B"."CUSTEMAILUPDATED" AS "CUSTEMAILUPDATED", 
"B"."CUSTPHONE3" AS "CUSTPHONE3", 
"B"."CUSTOPTOUT" AS "CUSTOPTOUT", 
"B"."CUSTLASTSYNCED" AS "CUSTLASTSYNCED", 
"B"."CUSTPREVIOUSEMAIL" AS "CUSTPREVIOUSEMAIL"
FROM "CUSTOMER" AS "B"
WHERE (CHAR_LENGTH("B"."CUSTPREVIOUSEMAIL")) > 0
```

Comment: Could you post generated SQL? `var query = _db.CUSTOMERs.Where(...); var sql = query.ToString();` Besides, there's no need to set type parameter explicitly, compiler can infer it from usage.

Comment: to make it work just add `i.CUSTPREVIOUSEMAIL != null &&` to your clause

Comment: Dennis, I added the generated SQL to my question.

Comment: Is it Firebird? Also, are you sure, that strings don't contain whitespace? Try to trim them first.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to check for null instead of 0.
try this
    foreach (CUSTOMER c in (_db.CUSTOMERs.Where(i => i.CUSTPREVIOUSEMAIL.ToLower()!="null" ))
    {...}

Comment: I tried this and it did not work.  It was already NOT returning records where the value was null.  It was, however, returning records where the value was an empty string (set to "").

Comment: I tested your code I got the same result. But it worked for (i => i.CUSTPREVIOUSEMAIL.ToLower()!="null")